# Relative velocity with relativistic speeds in 3D

Tags: velocity, relativity, relative-motion

I have a question regarding the relative velocities of two objects in $3$D space. If objects $A$ and $B$'s velocities are being observed by stationary observer $C$, what is the velocity vector $A$ will see $B$ with or vice versa. This question also assumes $A$ and $B$ are also going at relativistic speeds.

$$\mathbf{v}_A=(a,b,c)$$
$$\mathbf{v}_B=(d,e,f)$$

If we assume all the vector components are being multiplied by $c$ (the speed of light) and can't be greater than $1$, what would $B$'s velocity vector be from $A$'s perspective?

Comment: Could you describe the directions A and B are traveling relative to each other? I'm having difficulty visualizing your situation.

Comment: In this scenario, A and B could have velocities pointing in similar directions or opposing directions. I mainly want the mathematical formula to do the calculation with.

Comment: You're looking to find relative velocities, then?

Comment: In this example the vectors for velocity are broken into x, y, and z vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be rest frame $S$ (or lab frame, earth frame, etc) and $A$ be the moving frame $S'$.

**Transformation of velocity**

> Velocity of $B$ observed by $A$ is
> $$\mathbf{v}'=
> \frac{\mathbf{u}+
>       \left(
>         \dfrac{\gamma_{v}-1}{v^2}\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}-\gamma_{v}
>       \right)\mathbf{v}}
>       {\gamma_{v}
>        \left(
>          1-\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{v}}{c^2}
>        \right)}$$

where $\gamma_{v}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}$, $\mathbf{u}=(d,e,f)$ is the velocity of $B$ observed by $C$ and $\mathbf{v}=(a,b,c)$ is the velocity of $A$ observed by $C$

Please refer to the derivation in pp. 33-4 of the following [notes](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/%7ESteane/teaching/rel_A.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your help. This should help greatly with my research.

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak I would be interested in a derivation of this formula. Where could it be found?

Comment: @Quaerendo Please refer to pp. 33-4 of the following [*notes*](https://users.physics.ox.ac.uk/~smithb/website/coursenotes/rel_A.pdf).